# SharePoint 2010 with UAG - LDAP and AD users

Tags: active-directory, infrastructure, user-accounts, single-sign-on, ldap

We are trying to test the following setup.
We have a SharePoint Farm in our forest (setup to use Kerberos). The DC of the SharePoint farm domain contains an AD with external users and their attributes. We have a second domain in this forest containing internal users. For our forest we have a sun LDAP server containing all the users and their credentials.

We would like to authorize our users entering from the internet through an UAG with the LDAP server configured as Authentication Server. After Authentication is established we need to map the users credentials with an AD account in one of the domains (Attribute in LDAP to tell to map to which account) (Single Sign On constraint Kerberos delegation)

The question is, where do we configure the mapping between the UAG authentication and or AD user?

Any help or thoughts are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your going to need to add ad fs to your plan.

This should get you pointed in the right direction.
 http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd857388.aspx